# Converte String de uma array para Int - Java

Tags: java

Eu tenho um arquivo.csv que tem três informações dentro dele, um nome, um preço e uma quantidade, precisava converte a quantidade que está nesse arquivo separado por ",", para um Array e depois passar como parametro em uma lista, só que gera um erro.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String path = "E:\\Temp\\ws-eclipse\\ProjectFile\\sourcefile.csv";
    List<Fileswork> list = new ArrayList();
    
    try (BufferedReader bfReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){
            String line;
            while((line = bfReader.readLine()) != null){
                String []itens = line.split(",");
                
                String Name = itens[0].trim();
                double Price = Double.valueOf(itens[1].trim());
                int Quantity = Integer.parseInt(itens[2].trim());

                list.add(new Fileswork(Name, Quantity, Price));
            }
            
            for(Fileswork var : list) {
                System.out.println(var.getQuantity());
            }
            bfReader.close();
    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at Application.Program.main(Program.java:26)
```

> [image: Citação]

Comment: A princípio parece ser porque no registro não tem só números, tem uma aspas no final (`1"`). Se puder [edit] a pergunta adicionando algumas linhas do CSV (principalmente a que gera o erro), dá para ter mais certeza (além de podermos detectar outros possíveis erros)

Comment: Coloquei o trecho do arquivo que está em CSV, mas ele não tem esse ( 1 ").

Comment: Por favor não coloque essas informações como imagem ([leia o FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052) para entender o motivo), e sim como texto. De qualquer forma, eu sugiro que abra o arquivo em um editor de texto (pode ser até no notepad mesmo). É comum que o Excel e outros programas similares salvem o CSV com aspas, principalmente se forem campos configurados como texto (mas essas aspas não aparecem quando vc abre na própria planilha)

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema, não sabia sobre essa questão dos programas afetarem o texto colocado lá.